# Wildcard to get files by exact extension

Tags: batch-file, command-line

While diagnosing a larger batch script that needs to loop files with `*.log` extension I've found a funny behaviour. In a sample directory with files like this:

```
bar.log
foo.log
foo.log.ignore
foo.log.log-1676521099
not-related
```

... my little test script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DEF_LOG="C:\test\*.log"
for %%i in (%DEF_LOG%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

... prints this:

```
C:\test\bar.log
C:\test\foo.log
C:\test\foo.log.log-1676521099
```

Digging deeper, I've found that's how Windows wildcards have been designed:

```
C:\>dir "C:\test\*.log" /b
bar.log
foo.log
foo.log.log-1676521099
```

My question is: how can I list all files that end *exactly* with `.log`?

Comment: However, it is interesting that the file named test.log.txt do not pass C:\test\*.log filter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the behavior is short file names. Unless disabled, file names that exceed the old 8.3 format will be assigned a short name that does match the 8.3 format. If the extension exceeds 3 characters, then the short name will consist of the first 3 characters of the long name extension. Execute the `dir /x "C:\test\*.log"` to see the short names.

All commands will test both the long and the short name when looking for matches.

A common way to get your desired result is to use DIR /B piped to FINDSTR. Note that you should avoid using delayed expansion when expanding a FOR variable because that will corrupt values that contain `!`. The `!` character may appear in a file name.

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\test"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir *.log^|findstr /lie ".log"') do echo %%~fF
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus tip about `enabledelayedexpansion`—I've just verified that it mangles file names that contain exclamation marks. (Since I need that for another feature, I suspect my script needs a full rewrite.)

Answer (score 5):

The Easyiest and faster way to do that is to test the modifier %%~x with your extension.

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do if /i "%%~xa"==".log" echo %%a
pause
```

Comment: Good Catch sacha, i like it  (-_°)

Answer (score 2):

Use a check inside loop to get only files with desired extension

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem set desired extension for additional filter
set extn=.log
set DEF_LOG="C:\temp\*.log"

for %%i in (%DEF_LOG%) do (
    rem if file extension is equal to our ext
    if "%%~xi"=="%extn%" echo %%i
)
```