# How do you match an exact file extension under Windows/command line/file open dialog?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get a directory listing of only files with a given extension.  At first blush this seems to be a simple thing to do, however check out this simple example:

```
C:\CODE\metcal>dir /b *.exe
metcal.exe
metcal.exe1
```

Notice that this returns `metcal.**exe**` and `metcal.**exe1**` as matches.

With python files a similar thing happens:

```
C:\CODE\metcal>dir /b *.py
metcal.py
metcal.pyc
```

Notice again Windows has determined that `*.py` takes anything that starts with `*.py` so it captures the `.pyc` files as well.

Is there a way to get only the extensions that match exactly?  In the above python files example I would like the following to occur (obviously with the correct syntax substituted for *.py)

```
C:\CODE\metcal>dir /b *.py
metcal.py
```

As a note the matching under Windows not as simple as it seems.

`*.exe` matches  `foo.exe, foo.exe1, foo.exeabcde`  but **not** `foo.exe.bak`

There are other questions on SO that are similar that are related to long/short file names.  The *.py and *.pyc example here should not introduce name mangling machinery.

**I have experimented on XP and Win7 machines and this behavior is not consistent at the cmd Prompt and file open dialogs.  This inconsistant behavior makes me suspect this problem is related to settings of somekind. **

Comment: By "DOS" you mean the Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`, right?

Comment: I think the given pattern is also checked against the 8.3-format file name, so `*.exe` matches also `*.exe1`; if the extension is less than 3 characters long ,like `*.py`, it seems to work, files like `*.pyc` are not returned -- at least on my Windows 7 x64 machine... For precise filtering I use `findstr`, like this: `dir /B "*.exe" | findstr /L /E ".doc"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard to get files by exact extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761052/wildcard-to-get-files-by-exact-extension)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem described with `*.py`, which only matches `.py` files and not `.pyc` when I try it. Otherwise your problem seems to be identical to the one linked by Alex K.

Comment: When I do `dir *.py` I *don't* get any `.pyc` files, on Windows 7.

Comment: I have delved deeper based on Mark's response and sure enough the machine the code was running on was a windows XP machine. It seems that there is inconsistent file extension wild card matching on various OS's.  I just looked at an XP64, Win7/32, Win7/64 and each displayed slightly different behavior!

Answer (score 1):

It's because windows wildcards on extensions check both long and short names as explained in this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/238900/winxp-dir-command-3-and-4-char-extensions-are-the-same#238930

Solution there is to disable 8.3 names creation and then striping them on ntfs volumes which will also improve performance.

[Microsoft Docs: Fsutil 8dot3name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name)

> **Remarks:**
>   Permanently removing 8dot3 file names and not modifying registry keys that point to the 8dot3 file names may lead to unexpected application failures, including the inability to uninstall an application. It is recommended you first back up your directory or volume before you attempt to remove 8dot3 file names.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get only those extensions (`.py` and `.pyc`), you should try like this way :

```
@echo off
dir /b *.py*
pause
```

Comment: No that is the problem.  If I ask for *.py I expect ONLY .py extension but I'm getting .py AND .pyc...and .pyo.  What I'd like is to know the syntax for ONLY getting .py.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unix `ls` command from the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl) to do this, assuming you have WSL installed. It's freely available from Microsoft. From your Windows command prompt, type `wsl` followed by the `ls` command to list the files you want.

So, for your example, `wsl ls metcal.py` returns only metcal.py. To get the same results as you're seeing with `dir`, use `wsl ls metcal.py*`.