# Searching files filtering by extension returns too many results

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I'm developing a C++ console application that has to manage files on Windows OS. I need to obtain a 'list' of file names which have a specific extension. I've found a lot of solutions, the most suggested one is the following one:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\PWS\\*.sda", &data);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        cout << data.cFileName << endl;

    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Suppose I have these files inside the `C:\\PWS` folder:

- f001.sdac
- f002.sda
- f003.sdab
- f004.sda

The above code prints all of them, while I only need `f002.sda` and `f004.sda`.

Any hint?

`NB`: I don't want to use boost library.

Comment: ...but you could use C++'s filesystem library.

Comment: Have you tried `dir *.sda` on the **cmd** to see the result. It think this is a problem with windows wildcard

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761052/wildcard-to-get-files-by-exact-extension) suggests that the cause is that windows looks for a match of both the short 8.3 file name and the long file name. Either find a way to disable this behaviour for your process or use `FindFirstFile("C:\\PWS\\*")` and do the file extension filtering on your own, for instance using the [PathMatchSpec()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727(v=vs.85).aspx) function which only uses the strings you pass to it and won't check 8.3 name.

Comment: @k-five, point for you!

Comment: Using `boost` is much easier and cleaner if you can compile it. It has an extension method, so you can use ti to compare against your extension.

Comment: @zett42 donesn't `PathMatchSpec` have the behaviour we want to avoid (weird 8.3 filename matching) ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz No it doesn't. `PatchMatchSpec` is just a string matching function. As such it has no knowledge of the associated 8.3 name of a file.

Comment: Explanation of this behaviour: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883

Comment: @zett42 correct, I was confused by _"Microsoft MS-DOS wildcard match type."_ in the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I adopted is the following one:

```
void GetFilesByNameRootAndExtension(const string& dirPath, const string& nameRoot, string& ext, vector<string>& files)
{
    files.clear();

    stringstream ss;
    ss << dirPath << "\\" << nameRoot << "*" << ext;
    string searchKeyS = ss.str();
    const char* searchKey = searchKeyS.c_str();

    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(searchKey, &data);

    ext = ext.erase(0, 1);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            string fN = data.cFileName;
            if (fN.substr(fN.find_last_of(".") + 1) == ext) // filtering by extension
                files.push_back(fN);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Thank you everybody for your hints!

Answer (score 2):

The code also finds `"f001.sdac"` and `"f003.sdab"` because [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`FindFirstFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) match both the short (8.3) and long file names. For instance, the short file name for `"f001.sdac"` may be something like `"f~1.sda"`.

The reason for that is [backwards compatibility with 16-bit (sigh!) programs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883).

To work around this issue, call `FindFirstFile()` with the `*` wildcard to match all files and then do your own filtering, for instance by calling the [`PathMatchSpec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727(v=vs.85).aspx) function. `PathMatchSpec()` does string matching only so it doesn't have the weird behaviour of `FindFirstFile()`.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;    
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW( L"C:\\PWS\\*", &data );
if( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
{
    do 
    {
        if( ( data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) == 0 && 
            PathMatchSpecW( data.cFileName, L"*.sda" ) )
        {
            std::wcout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
        }
    } 
    while( FindNextFileW( hFind, &data ) );

    FindClose( hFind );
}
```

**Side note:** Calling `FindFirstFileEx()` with the value of `FindExInfoBasic` for the `fInfoLevelId` parameter, which supposedly "*does not query the short file name*", is not a valid solution for this issue because it will still match short (8.3) file names.

Comment: The phrase "does not query the short file name" simply means that the short name is not included in the returned data.  It isn't supposed to change the way the search is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should filter the results for you:

```
bool hasFileExtension(TCHAR cFileName[], TCHAR* ptcExtension)
{
    bool result = true;
    int iFileNameLength = _tcslen(cFileName);
    int iExtensionLength = _tcslen(ptcExtension);

    if (iFileNameLength >= iExtensionLength)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < iExtensionLength + 1 && result; i++)
        {
            if (cFileName[iFileNameLength - i] != ptcExtension[iExtensionLength - i])
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

void listFilesWithExtension(LPCTSTR lpFileName, TCHAR* ptcExtension)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(lpFileName, &data);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if (hasFileExtension(data.cFileName, ptcExtension))
            {
                wcout << data.cFileName << endl;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR lpFileName = L"C:\\PWS\\*.sda";
    TCHAR* ptcExtension = _T(".sda");
    listFilesWithExtension(lpFileName, ptcExtension);
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```