# Directory.GetFiles doesn't pick up all files

Tags: c#, filenames

I have some code that is meant to get files in a directory, which is simple enough

```cs
foreach (var Totalfile in new DirectoryInfo(rootfolder).GetFiles("*Totals*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
```

The files are named as follows:

```
Totals.CSV142344
Totals.CSV142409
Totals.CSV142433
Totals.CSV142501
Totals.CSV142528
```

My issue is that it is not picking up the last file.

I have fixed the code by putting this instead:

```cs
foreach (var Totalfile in new DirectoryInfo(rootfolder).GetFiles("*Totals*.csv*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
```

Saying get any files that contains both Totals and .csv, with anything after the .csv.

What I don't get is why it got the top four files, but not the bottom.

I'd have thought none of the files would be picked up by the original code?

Comment: Has the file in question been deleted, but is kept open by antivirus or similar? This might lead to a "ghost" file where explorer still lists it, but it doesn't actually exist on disk any more.

Comment: Apparently the first four files have [a 8.3 name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920957/searching-files-filtering-by-extension-returns-too-many-results#comment76823268_44920957) and the last one does not.

Comment: The short name is your nemesis, when there are too many files then `Totals~n.csv` no longer fits and you can only get a match on `Total*`.  Type `dir /x tot*.*` to see short names.  You favor `Totals.csv*` and may have to filter to eliminate accidental matches.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently `GetFiles` adheres to the pattern matching logic as it is implemented in say the `dir` command.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

> Because this method checks against file names with both the 8.3 file
>   name format and the long file name format, a search pattern similar to
>   `"*1*.txt"` may return unexpected file names. For example, using a
>   search pattern of `"*1*.txt"` returns "longfilename.txt" because the
>   equivalent 8.3 file name format is "LONGFI~1.TXT".

As @GSerg pointed some of your files have a matching 8.3 name.

```
dir /x *Totals*.csv*

2020-01-31  09:33                 0 TOTALS~1.CSV Totals.CSV142344
2020-01-31  09:33                 0 TOTALS~2.CSV Totals.CSV142409
2020-01-31  09:33                 0 TOTALS~3.CSV Totals.CSV142433
2020-01-31  09:33                 0 TOTALS~4.CSV Totals.CSV142501
2020-01-31  09:33                 0 TO5404~1.CSV Totals.CSV142528
```

Try changing the pattern to `Totals.csv*` to match all files.